# I have multiple dictionaries in one variable results. How to return only 1st dictionary value from that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, nested

**I have multiple dictionaries in one variable results. How to return only 1st dictionary value from that?**

```
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Output is :

```
{'Title': 'John'}
{'Title': 'Mark'}
{'Title': 'Adam'}
{'Title': 'Ethen'}
{'Title': 'Tom'}
```

**I want to return value of 1st dictionary 'john'**

Comment: `return results[0]`?

Comment: No, it's not working. We need value, it's returning both key and it's value

Comment: I think you should clarify your expected result, then.

Comment: can you provide the type (results) value

Comment: You can also use: `list(results[0].values())[0]` (i.e. value of first key in first dictionary of list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict's key to access the value

```
print(results[0]['Title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list or a tuple of dictionaries, you can use indexing:

```
results[0]
```

Where the `0` corresponds to the first dictionary from the list as indexing in Python starts at 0.

Comment: It's returning {'Title': 'John'}. But i need only john value

Comment: So you have to get the value from the dictionary: `results[0]['Title']`

Comment: For the future, please be more specific with your question. Otherwise, you will get non-helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

it is best to change keys of the dictionary.
or you can use var[0]
or use var[title]

Answer (score 0):

```
print(results[0]["title"])
```

you don't need to use a loop if you just want the values of the first item

Answer (score 0):

You might want to format your output as a *list* of dicts such that the output is

```py
result = [
{'Title': 'John'},
{'Title': 'Mark'},
{'Title': 'Adam'},
{'Title': 'Ethen'},
{'Title': 'Tom'}
]
```

Then it is clear to see that you can get `'John'` by indexing `result[0]['Title']`

Answer (score 0):

dict.values() can be used

```
results=({'Title': 'John'},{'Title': 'Mark'},{'Title': 'Adam'},{'Title': 'Ethen'},{'Title': 'Tom'})
d=results[0]    #to store first dictionary
print(d.values())  #to get value of first dictionary
```